# Como puedo desactivar el doble click de un ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, xml

pido orientación en el siguiente código, no se si estoy haciendo lo correcto, tengo una activity con dos fragments el primer fragment esta en un tablayout y el arreglo de fragments y este tiene diferentes botones o ImageButton, que al dar doble click levanta el segundo fragment, la idea hasta alli es como yo lo quiero, pero el codigo no se si es de la forma correcta aunque funciona aca le muestro.

(1)

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ();     
fragmentTransaction.commit ();
```

(2)

```
private ArrayList< Fragment > agregarFragment(){
        Log.e ("MainActivity", "agregarFragments");
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<> ();
        fragments.add (new ExplorarFragment ());
        return fragments;
    }
    private void setTupViewPager(){
        viewPager.setAdapter (new PageAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager (), agregarFragment()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager (viewPager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt (0).setText ("Exprorar");
    }
```

obviamente todo esto esta en MainActivity

(1) aunque funciona me parece que no es una forma adecuada de cargar el fragment teniendo ya un arreglo de fragments, ademas que suspendi una linea que inflava otra vez el mismo fragmentExplorar

(2) en el dos no hay problema. Agradezco la orientación o la forma adecuada de hacerlo.  y gracias

Comment: Deberías agregar el código del ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolverlo quitando

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

de mi Imagebutton